# Enable error logging from settings.php

Tags: 7, debugging, log-messages

I am facing a *The website encountered an unexpected error.* error while setting up the site.

Most of the documentation I found online suggest to enable logging in the *setting.php* file.

I added this line in *site/default/settings.php*.

```php
$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';
```

I added the following code.

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

I added the following lines to the same *settings.php* file, at the bottom.

```php
if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/settings.local.php')) {
  include __DIR__ . '/settings.local.php';
}
```

I copied the *sites/example.sites.php* file to *sites/default/* and renamed it *settings.local.php*, as suggested on
https://catwolf.org/qs?id=180d30e9-9dcb-4e96-b030-7df34c77f5ab&x=x and https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2018-07-18/enable-drupal-8-backend-errorlogdebugging-mode.

I restarted Apache and reloaded the site, but I see the same error shows again without any log.

I am migrating a Drupal 7.84 site from CentOS 6.10 to CentOS 7.9. The httpd passes from version 2.2.15 to version 2.4.6; it also has PHP 7.03 and MariaDB 10.3.

Did I miss anything, or do I have to do anything else to enable the logging?

Comment: If you added those settings just below `<?php`, make sure that they are not overwritten later in the file. Also, `example.sites.php` is not a template for `settings.local.php`.

BTW - What is your version of Drupal? In 7 the setting name was different.

Comment: My drupal version is 7.84. I don't know where I have to add this line. Once I resolve this I will remove those lines as it is the production server. I am in the migration process. I am migrating the drupal 7.84 site from centos 6.10 to centos 7.9. Httpd version also changes from 2.2.15 to 2.4.6. Php v7.03 and mariadb v10.3. I hope this info may help

Comment: If you are temporarily adding lines to a file to try to change things, always add them to the bottom of the file first.  This will ensure that the lines override any logic in the file because they will be the last to be executed.

Comment: Added as you said @patrick but no luck. shows asusual same error

Answer (score 1):

Here's the official manual for Drupal 7: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/show-all-errors-while-developing

At the end of your `sites/default/settings.php`, add the following lines:

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
$conf['error_level'] = 2;
```

Please pay extra attention to the last line, as it is specific to D7. Your code was for D8/D9.

Of course those changes can be also made to `settings.local.php`, but I would try to do it after making sure that `$conf['error_level'] = 2;` works at all at the end of `settings.php`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @grzegorz. I tried to add it at the end of the setting.php file but no luck. Do you know why it didn't execute?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

- in the webroot, rename `.htaccess` to `.htaccess.old` -- Apache 2.4 has changed syntax in some directives that may be causing the error before PHP is even reached. Also check apache log files ( usually `/var/log/httpd/error.log`, see your VirtualHost for other paths )
- check your PHP file logs, since some errors never make it to the screen even with all the above listed directives -- on CentOS these are normally under `/var/log/php*`

One of the above should have a log entry on what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion @nick i checked all the logs you mentioned 

For apache log,
`[core:notice] [pid 22268] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Tue May 03 07:22:21.732165 2022] 
[suexec:notice] [pid 22268] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)`........


For php log 
`fpm is running, pid 1497
 NOTICE: ready to handle connections
 NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
 NOTICE: Terminating 
 NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!`.........

I disabled the firewall and SELinux but shows the same error

Comment: I renamed the .htaccess file as you mentioned and reloaded the  apache and site but same error appears